# VB.NET Using a dllimport in a portable class library

Tags: vb.net, windows-runtime

I wanted to change my usercontrol to a portable class library.

However, in this line of my code...

```
<DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.StdCall)> _
Public Function UnhookWindowsHookEx(ByVal idHook As Integer) As Boolean
End Function
```

... I get the error "Type ''DllImport'' is not defined''.

What am I doing wrong here and how could I fix that?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

In order for a library to be classified as portable it needs to adhere to a set of restrictions that include **not** supporting `DllImport`. Across the various operating systems that can use a portable class library, directly using native operating system calls isn't supported.

In this case, you would need to break the component into two or more pieces. The control that needs the call to `UnhookWindowsHookEx` would need to use a second platform specific component which implements the functionality, abstracting it from the UserControl. This could be done for example by using a platform specific class that implements an interface: `INativeAccess`. At run time, it would use the platform specific class if available. There is more on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn641187%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) about this.

Comment: Hmmm, thank you. Somehow I am under the impression that it gets extraordinarly complicated. Is it just that I am getting old, or will one get used to this kind of complexity when done for a few weeks? I have a MiniMac here, did some XCode for a few weeks, hated it and gave it a rest, hoping that MS would be nicer. But right now MS looks much XCode. Or am I exaggerating it?

Comment: I suppose it's mostly what you're accustomed to and what you like personally. I've never liked Objective-C personally and think Microsoft development tools are quite good. The code you've asked about though really is a platform thing. A native call like the one you want is very low level and wouldn't be portable (as it targets Win32). For some APIs, there are .NET equivalents. It's unusual to require that API, and the entire control is likely best left within a platform specific assembly.

Answer (score -1):

Just like any type you want to use in code, you must have referenced the assembly that the `DllImportAttribute` class is defined in in order to use it.  You must also have imported the namespace that it's a member of to use it unqualified.  Have you done both of those things?

Even if you have, the whole point of a portable class library is that it's portable.  Is that API going to be supported on all the platforms you might port it to?